# NoSuchElementException thrown in a populated CSV file

Tags: java

Couple friends are trying to get more versatile in DotA, so I am trying to write a program that gives everyone random roles and then records whether our team won or lost that game, and then updates everyones winrates accordingly by role (There are 5 roles, and then I am also including "coach" in the event that we have someone watching, the merit being that the same person doesn't have to sit out every game)

I chose to use java because its the language I am using in school right now, so naturally I want each player to be an object and all of their individual data is stored with the object, and then I am using a CSV table to store these values so that the next time I run the program everyone still has the same statistics, but this is where problems are arising.

Here is what I have so far, basically just trying to get objects to behave correctly before I get to work on everything else.

main.java, player.java, and data.csv are the files that are part of this project.

main.java

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("data.csv");
        if(file.createNewFile()){
            System.out.println("data.csv File Created in Project root directory");
        }else System.out.println("File data.csv already exists in the project root directory");

        player[][] players = new player[15][1];
       int n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<14; i++)
        {       
            player player = new player();
            players[i][0]=player;
            n++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            players[i][0].getData(file);
            System.out.println(players[i][0]);
        }


    }
}
```

player.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;

public class player {   
    String playerName;
    private int winsTotal, wins1, wins2, wins3, wins4, wins5, winsCoach, gamesTotal, games1, games2, games3, games4, games5, gamesCoach, index;
    public int flag = 0;
    public void Player() {
        winsTotal = 0;
        wins1 = 0;
        wins2 = 0;
        wins3 = 0;
        wins4 = 0;
        wins5 = 0;
        winsCoach = 0;
        gamesTotal = 0;
        games1 = 0;
        games2 = 0;
        games3 = 0;
        games4 = 0;
        games5 = 0;
        gamesCoach = 0;
        }

    public void getData(File f) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
        s.useDelimiter(",");
        try {
        this.playerName = s.next();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.playerName = "null";
        }

        try {
        this.wins1 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.wins1 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.wins2 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.wins2 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.wins3 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.wins3 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.wins4 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.wins4 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.wins5 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.wins5 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.winsCoach = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.winsCoach = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.winsTotal = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.winsTotal = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.gamesTotal = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.gamesTotal = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.games1 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.games1 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.games2 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.games2 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.games3 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.games3 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.games4 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.games4 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.games5 = s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.games5 = 0;
        }

        try {
        this.gamesCoach= s.nextInt();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e)
        {
            this.gamesCoach = 0;
        }

        s.nextLine();
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Name: "+playerName+"\tWins as Carry: "+wins1+"\tWins as Mid: "+wins2+"\tWins as Offlane: "+wins3+"\tWins as 4 Support: "+wins4+"\tWins as 5 Support: "+wins5+"\tWins as Coach: "+winsCoach+"\tPlayed games: "+gamesTotal+"\tGames as Carry: "+games1+"\tGames as Mid: "+games2+"\tGames as Offlane: "+games3+"\tGames as 4 support: "+games4+"\tGames as 5 support: "+games5+"\tGames as Coach: "+gamesCoach;
    }

    }
```

[Screenshot of data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb3fr.png)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Have a look at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: The try/catch that goes on for like a hundred lines is more of me just trying to get the thing to work in the first place, if that is what you are referring to. My issue is that for some reason the scanner isn't picking up on anything, despite the fact that there is, in fact, data inside the file. I don't know, as of right now, what is causing the scanner to be caught up. I do know that it bugs out in the loop where I am using N as the stopping point rather than just an arbitrary number, because when I replace N with 0 (so the loop doesn't run) everything works fine.